# Why doesn't \begin{center} center my LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

Why doesn't this print out centered?

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{pmatrix}\mu_{G_i, S}\\
    \mu_{G_j, S}
    \end{pmatrix} &\sim  N
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0\\
    0
    \end{pmatrix}\!\!,&
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & \rho \\
    \rho & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
    \end{bmatrix}  
\end{center}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your input is erroneous. The `pmatrix` and `bmatrix` environments require math-mode, which the `center` environment doesn't provide. The output shows an off-center (left-aligned) equation, which happens as a result of TeX trying to fix the mistake by inserting an inline math-mode switch `$`.

Here's probably what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \mu_{G_i, S} \\
    \mu_{G_j, S}
  \end{pmatrix}
  \sim  N
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 \\
    0
    \end{pmatrix}, &
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & \rho \\
    \rho & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
  \end{bmatrix}  
\]

\end{document}
```

`\[`...`\]` marks a display math equation, with content horizontally centred.